Date input is not automatically formatting with slashes (/)
The issue is that the date input is not automatically formatting with slashes (/), and the virtual keyboard lacks a slash key, preventing manual entry in the MM/DD/YYYY format. I'm using react-native-paper-dates library. If I add the date for example 1234567891, it will format it: 01/14/7892, so it needs 10 digits to format the code.
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Button, Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import {DatePickerModal, TimePickerModal} from 'react-native-paper-dates';

import NewRow from './NewRow';

import {fontSize} from '../resources/fontSize';
import {colors} from '../resources/colors';
import {theme} from '../resources/theme';
import moment from 'moment';

interface Time {
  hours: string;
  minutes: string;
}

interface State {
  isDatePickerVisible: boolean;
  date: Date | null;
  isTimePickerVisible: boolean;
  time: Time | null;
}

interface Props {
  title: string;
  time: string;
  onDateSelected: (date: Date) => void;
  onTimeSelected: (date: Time) => void;
  initialDate?: string;
  initialTime?: string;
  mode?: 'date' | 'time' | 'datetime' | undefined;
  dateFormat?: string;
  edit?: any;
  haveEnd?: boolean;
  haveStart?: boolean;
}

/**
 * Date picker component based on `react-native-paper-dates`
 */
class PickDateAndTime extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    const date =
      props.initialDate !== null ? new Date(props.initialDate) : null;

    const time =
      props.initialTime !== null && props.initialTime !== undefined
        ? {
            hours: props.initialTime.split(':')[0],
            minutes: props.initialTime.split(':')[1],
          }
        : null;

    this.state = {
      isDatePickerVisible: false,
      date,
      isTimePickerVisible: false,
      time,
    };
  }

  toggleDatePicker = (): void => {
    this.setState(preState => ({
      isDatePickerVisible: !preState.isDatePickerVisible,
    }));
  };

  toggleTimePicker = (): void => {
    this.setState(preState => ({
      isTimePickerVisible: !preState.isTimePickerVisible,
    }));
  };

  handleTimePicked = (time: any): void => {
    const newTime = time ?? new Date().getTime();

    this.setState({time: newTime, isTimePickerVisible: false});

    this.props.onTimeSelected(newTime);
  };

  handleDatePicked = (date: any): void => {
    const newDate = date.date ?? new Date();

    this.setState({date: newDate, isDatePickerVisible: false});

    this.props.onDateSelected(newDate);
  };

  render(): React.ReactElement {
    const {date, isDatePickerVisible, time, isTimePickerVisible} = this.state;
    const {dateFormat} = this.props;

    const displayText =
      date != null
        ? dateFormat !== ''
          ? dayjs(date).format(dateFormat)
          : date
        : '';
    // const displayTime = time ? (time.hours + ':' + time.minutes) : ('')
    const displayTime = time != null ? moment(time as any).format('HH:mm') : '';

    return (
      <PaperProvider theme={{...theme}}>
        <DatePickerModal
          locale="en"
          mode={'single'}
          label={
            this.props.edit === true ? 'Izmenite datum' : 'Izaberite datum'
          }
          animationType={'fade'}
          saveLabel="Potvrdi"
          visible={isDatePickerVisible}
          onDismiss={this.toggleDatePicker}
          date={date ?? new Date()}
          onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
          startYear={1950}
          validRange={{
            endDate: this.props.haveEnd ? new Date() : undefined,
            startDate: this.props.haveStart ? new Date() : undefined,
          }}
        />
        <TimePickerModal
          visible={isTimePickerVisible}
          onDismiss={this.toggleTimePicker}
          onConfirm={this.handleTimePicked}
          // hours={Number(time?.hours ?? '00')}
          // minutes={Number(time?.minutes ?? '00')}
          label={
            this.props.edit === true ? 'Izmenite vreme' : 'Izaberite vreme'
          }
          uppercase={true}
          cancelLabel="Otkaži"
          confirmLabel="Potvrdi"
          animationType="fade"
          inputFontSize={33}
          locale="en"
        />
        <NewRow height={10} />
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            width: '100%',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
          }}>
          <View style={{width: '45%', marginLeft: 10}}>
            {this.props.edit === true ? (
              <Button
                mode={'outlined'}
                style={[styles.buttonStyle]}
                labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
                onPress={this.toggleDatePicker}>
                {'Izmeni datum'}
              </Button>
            ) : (
              <Button
                mode={'outlined'}
                style={[styles.buttonStyle]}
                labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
                onPress={this.toggleDatePicker}>
                {'Dodaj datum'}
              </Button>
            )}
          </View>
          <View style={{width: '45%', marginRight: 10}}>
            {this.props.edit === true ? (
              <Button
                mode={'outlined'}
                style={[styles.buttonStyle]}
                labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
                onPress={this.toggleTimePicker}>
                {'Izmeni vreme'}
              </Button>
            ) : (
              <Button
                mode={'outlined'}
                style={[styles.buttonStyle]}
                labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
                onPress={this.toggleTimePicker}>
                {'Dodaj vreme'}
              </Button>
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
        <NewRow height={10} />
        {displayText !== '' && (
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 20}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.blue,
                fontSize: fontSize.font16,
                fontWeight: 'normal',
              }}>
              {'Datum: '}
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.blue,
                fontSize: fontSize.font16,
                fontWeight: 'normal',
              }}>
              {displayText.toString()}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
        {displayTime !== '' && (
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 20}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.blue,
                fontSize: fontSize.font16,
                fontWeight: 'normal',
              }}>
              {'Vreme: '}
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.blue,
                fontSize: fontSize.font16,
                fontWeight: 'normal',
              }}>
              {displayTime}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </PaperProvider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    borderColor: colors.blue,
  },
  labelStyle: {
    color: colors.blue,
    fontSize: fontSize.font12,
 fontWeight: '700',

  },
});

export default PickDateAndTime;



Your problem is related to how date input and formatting are handled in your component.

Install react-native-mask-text
npm install react-native-mask-text

Use MaskedTextInput for date formatting


import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { MaskedTextInput } from 'react-native-mask-text';
import { Button, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { DatePickerModal } from 'react-native-paper-dates';

const PickDateAndTime = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState('');
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleDatePicked = (selectedDate: Date) => {
    const formattedDate = dayjs(selectedDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    setDate(formattedDate);
    setDatePickerVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <DatePickerModal
        locale="en"
        mode="single"
        visible={isDatePickerVisible}
        onDismiss={() => setDatePickerVisible(false)}
        date={new Date()}
        onConfirm={handleDatePicked}
        saveLabel="Confirm"
      />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MaskedTextInput
          mask="99/99/9999"
          value={date}
          onChangeText={(text) => setDate(text)}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <Button onPress={() => setDatePickerVisible(true)}>
          Pick Date
        </Button>
      </View>
      {date ? (
        <View>
          <Text>Selected Date: {date}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 20,
  },
  input: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 18,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default PickDateAndTime;


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In addition to above, when you're making modifications to the OP source code, try making some indication of changed parts, or write a description of parts that you have edited.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
